# IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py'

Tags: python, pip

Why am I getting this:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py'
```

after I ran `pip install django==1.9` and is it a problem?

Comment: try run your code with `sudo pip install django==1.9`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are seeing this when you are installing, yes it's a problem because it means django hasn't been installed properly. You shouldn't be installing stuff into the global python system anyway. You should create a `virtualenv` for use with django

If you are seeing this wheny you are trying to execute `django-admin.py` you can change it's permissions

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/django-admin.py
```

But you should use a virtualenv anyway

Comment: Yes, that was it. I had forgotten to activate the `virtualenv`.

Comment: glad to have helped

Comment: Uh oh.  I forgot to create a virtualenv too.  What will the side effects be?

Comment: You don't always get side effects by forgetting to create a virtualenv, but occaisionally it comes back to bite you for example when you project is dependent on a specific version of a library but the system has updated