# Getting Error while installing djangorestframework - Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangorestframework-3.6.3.dist-info'

Tags: python, django

I want to install Django rest framework in fedora-25 but when I run this command :

```
pip install djangorestframework
```

I'm getting following error:

```
Collecting djangorestframework
Using cached djangorestframework-3.6.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: djangorestframework
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 326, in run
strip_file_prefix=options.strip_file_prefix,
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 742, in install
**kwargs
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 834, in install
strip_file_prefix=strip_file_prefix
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1037, in move_wheel_files
strip_file_prefix=strip_file_prefix,
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 346, in move_wheel_files
clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 317, in clobber
ensure_dir(destdir)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
os.makedirs(path)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangorestframework-3.6.3.dist-info'
You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

And when I try above command with **sudo** , getting following error

```
Collecting djangorestframework
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f0011a7bf10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/djangorestframework/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f0013a4fe50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/djangorestframework/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f0011788050>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/djangorestframework/
```

And When I tried to upgrade pip

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

again I'm getting Permission denied error and when I run it with **sudo** , getting following error

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7eff30658ed0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7eff3262cf10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/pip/
```

What should I do ? Is there any other way to install djangorestframework ?

Please help me out this :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IOError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44047382/ioerror-errno-13-permission-denied-usr-local-bin-django-admin-py)

Comment: What happens if you run `sudo pip install djangorestframework`?

Comment: I have mentioned that error also @MattCremeens

Comment: Have you tried using a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/)?

Comment: No. Actually I don't have idea about virtualenv

Comment: @user2896976 How can I install djangorestframework using virtualenv could you describe little bit more

Comment: You create a virtualenv by doing `virtualenv -p python venv` in your project directory, which creates an isolated python installation in your project folder. Then do `source venv/bin/activate` to tell bash to use the python in your local dir instead of the system dir. Then proceed to install whatever dependencies you need. Once you've installed your dependencies run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to generate a list of the deps and their versions for easy installation.

Comment: @user2896976 Could you please tell me How can I upgrade pip from 8.1.0 to 9.0.1. I have tried using 'pip install --upgrade pip' But it's not working!!

Comment: Yes Now it works with sudo with adding proxy in command `sudo pip install --proxy 10.3.100.207:8080 djangorestframework` Thank You all of you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a virtualenv.

```
sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
virtualenv myvenvname // create ur env
source myvenvname/bin/activate // activate it if it isnt already activated
```

Install all of your packages inside your virtual environment to avoid conflicts with other packages, this might solve ur problem.

One other thing is, you're trying to install it using python 2.7 as I've seen. Is this the version that you want? If you want to install it using python 3 do:

```
pip3 install djangorestframework
```

Comment: Actually, your problem really looks like that you're trying to install a python 3.6 package using python 2.7.

Comment: I think all of this problem because of pip's old version which is 8.1.0 So could you please tell me how can I upgrade it to 9.0.1. @gabrielbelini

Comment: I have tried using 'pip install --upgrade pip' but it's not working

Comment: Try this one `sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip`, Have you tried using `sudo pip install djangorestframework`?

Comment: Yes Now it works with sudo with adding proxy in command `sudo pip install --proxy 10.3.100.207:8080 djangorestframework` Thank You.

Comment: you're welcome, if I helped answer your question you can select answered in my post, thanks!